# How to add Infinite Scroll to BigCommerce Category page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bigcommerce

I am trying to add infinite scroll to the category page on BigCommerce. [Infinite Scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/)

I have uploaded the JS script to the content file on webdav and inserted the HTML code on the `category.html` page but it won't work. I think because it's a partial page that gets injected into the `base.html`. I have added the script into that page to no avail. I am not sure how to call the script with jQuery or JavaScript as shown in the instructions.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initializing Infinite Scroll on grid.html (or whichever template file creates the `<ul>` for the category products in your theme). Here's an example using the HTML initialization method, applied to the grid.html file from Cornerstone:

```
<ul class="productGrid" data-infinite-scroll='{ "path": ".pagination-link", "append": ".product", "history": false }'>
{{#each products}}
<li class="product">
    {{>components/products/card show_compare=../show_compare show_rating=../settings.show_product_rating theme_settings=../theme_settings customer=../customer}}
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Just be sure that you are referencing the Infinite Scroll .js files in the {{head}} section of base.html, either with the path to the file in WebDAV, or using the CDN link:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@3/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.js"></script>
```

**Edit:**
Updating after a [user reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54675696/infinite-scroll-js-loads-same-products-on-scroll-instead-of-products-from-next/54677398#54677398) that this is now duplicating the first page of category products. New markup making path specific to Next link:

```
data-infinite-scroll='{ "path": ".pagination-item--next .pagination-link", "append": ".product", "history": false }'
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I just need to find out how to remove the pagination links at the bottom of the page - I removed it from the head of the Category page but the links still persist. It gives the impression there are more products when you have actually gone through all of them. Excellent job Karen!

Comment: Glad that helped Christian! I think the easiest route for hiding the pagination links at the bottom would be using CSS to display: none on the element. I tried commenting out the pagination component from the template file, but it seemed to break things with Infinite Scroll. :)

Comment: So I worked out by disabling the pagination in '_settings.scss' the pagination numbers are removed. What remains is the forward arrow on the right that still takes you to page 2 where the back arrow then appears on the left.  Is there a separate setting for these?

Comment: There are probably a few different ways to achieve this, but I'd recommend wrapping a <div> around the pagination component on product-listing.html and setting a unique id on the div. Then, you can add CSS to themes.scss or wherever you're adding your custom CSS to target the ID. That way, you can hide the entire pagination element on the category page without affecting the blog pagination as well.

Comment: That worked no problems at all. Thank you so much for your help! Now on to the next mod of adding a date time picker to the checkout page!!!

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. Shouldn't there be a way to show a message that "No more products available" or something similar?

Comment: I've encountered a bug that I've been unable to resolve. The issue arises when I use the "Sort By" filter on the category page. After changing the sorting option, the Infinite Scroll functionality ceases to work, and I need to reload the page to get it functioning again manually. I'm seeking guidance on addressing this issue and ensuring a seamless experience with Infinite Scroll even after changing the sorting options.

Answer (score -1):

Npm is the best way to use infinite scroll

**Install with npm:**

```
npm install infinite-scroll
```

**Install with yarn:**

```
yarn add infinite-scroll
```

Comment: Do you happen to be the author of the linked article? If so, please note that when linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Also, having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.