# Infinite Scroll.js loads same products on scroll, instead of products from next page - BigCommerce issue?

Tags: lazy-loading, infinite-scroll, autoload, bigcommerce

I tried the same code as mentioned in the link below, but for some reason on my end it loads (clones) only the items from the current page, not the ones from the next page ???? Any ideas why ?

[How to add Infinite Scroll to BigCommerce Category page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848501/how-to-add-infinite-scroll-to-bigcommerce-category-page/54658449#54658449)

```
<ul class="productGrid" data-infinite-scroll='{ "path": ".pagination-link", "append": ".product", "history": false }'>
{{#each products}}
<li class="product">
    {{>components/products/card show_compare=../show_compare show_rating=../settings.show_product_rating theme_settings=../theme_settings customer=../customer}}
</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@3/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all pagination links have the class `.pagination-link`, including the numbered ones (1,2,3 etc). What's happening is that the Infinite Scroll library is grabbing the first element with that class, which happens to be page=1, so that's the first page that's being appended.

Try updating your code to this to specify that the path link should be the 'Next' pagination link:

```
<ul class="productGrid" data-infinite-scroll='{ "path": ".pagination-item--next .pagination-link", "append": ".product", "history": false }'>
    {{#each products}}
    <li class="product">
            {{>components/products/card settings=../settings show_compare=../show_compare show_rating=../settings.show_product_rating theme_settings=../theme_settings customer=../customer event=../event position=(add @index 1)}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Thanks for the heads up--I'll update my previous answer on the post you linked to :)

Comment: Thanks for replying, Karen. I thought that might be the problem and even tried to give custom class/id for pagination-item, still doesn't work. It loads on the scroll down, but this time it doesn't clone the products from the same page, just loads, stops and that's it, the next page products are still not showing. Do you have any other ideas ??? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's odd--I've got the code working in a sandbox here: https://karensandbox.mybigcommerce.com/bar.html . Do you see any console errors or anything like that on your side? For reference, I'm using Cornerstone v 3.1.1.

Comment: I don't have any errors in the console log. The original theme was Cornerstone 3.0, but I had to downgrade to older version 2.6.0 due to the fact that in 3.0 there is no option to display cart total on home page in header. So now I'm with 2.6.0. The example in the sandbox looks and works great, I wish mine was the same.

Comment: Just tested on 2.1.0 and it worked, so I'm not sure the version is the issue. To load the cart resource on 3.0 though, you can flip this flag to true in your config.json file: https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/master/config.json#L327 . Loading the cart resource globally is resource-intensive, so we changed the default behavior for performance reasons, but this flag will allow you to load the cart totals globally again.

Comment: Thank you for the cart advice, I will definitely use it in the future projects to come. I just tested the scroll on Cornerstone 3.0.0 , still no success. Not sure what's wrong on my end, which is obvious, since you got it to work on old and new version.

Comment: Happy to help troubleshoot if you want to email me the theme bundle: karen.white@bigcommerce.com

Comment: Thank you, Karen! I sent you a tunnel link, maybe you will see something that I don't.

Comment: Hey Samuil, just wanted to follow up. It doesn't look like I received your email?

Comment: Karen, you were right, it does work! My mistake was that I was testing it only locally. Once I uploaded the theme, it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: woohoo! awesome :)